# S3 permission for hosting public images for a web app

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I've started using S3 to host images connected to Rails models. Images are not uploaded by users so I just use aws_sdk gem to store images to S3 buckets.

So far I've succeeded in storing the image, but I am confused about the permission. Maybe I'm wrong but it seems most of the documents talking about S3 permission are outdated and I can't find what they are referring to.

What I want to do is pretty basic. I just want to host images and the image themselves are public so anyone can view. However I don't want anyone to just access my bucket and see everything else that's hosted there. So basically it's just a normal web app that hosts images on S3. How and where can I change the permission settings so it works that way? Currently the access is only granted to myself and images are not viewable by typing the url in a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:
It seems that it's not as simple as setting something as "public" and expect everything to work. Basically you need to write a policy and apply it to a bucket if you want your bucket to be viewable by public.

Here's the page where you can build your policy: http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496026/permissions-of-files-on-s3 Can you please elaborate about how you set up the policies.

Answer (score 7):

For people that are looking for more specific information on how to write a policy that allows anyone to access an s3 bucket this may be helpful.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This, and other examples at, the link below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2

If your are still having issues, check your block settings.

Comment: This is definitely the correct way. I wish I could mark it as such for other people who happen here post February 2022.

Also worth noting that if you go to the "Permissions" tab for the bucket in question you can edit the bucket policy and there's a UI to help you select the different actions you want with links to info on each action. Makes it dead easy to setup the policy you want.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the docs, more specific at the S3Objects write method: [Class: AWS::S3::S3Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#write-instance_method), which allows you to set a bunch of options for the uploaded file.

When uploading to your S3 bucket you have so set the proper `:acl` permission, because its default is `:private` and no public access is granted. Here's a modified snippet I grabbed from [github](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/samples/s3/upload_file.rb):

```
# get an instance of the S3 interface using the default configuration
s3 = AWS::S3.new

# create a bucket
b = s3.buckets.create('example')

# upload a file
basename = File.basename('image.png')
o = b.objects[basename]
o.write(:file => file_name,  :acl => :public_read)

# grab public url
image_public_url = o.public_url

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question was about the permission. I already had all the code, but it just wasn't running because of the permission problem.